# How to access FragmentManger from context from a class that does not extend FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am developing an android application in which I need to launch an Fragment from the class which doesnot extend  FragmentActivity . I am using support v4 package.
I will having the context in my current class. Can any one help me how to create FragmentManager object from current context?

```
public ToolBarGenerator(Context c)
{
      context = c;
}

FragmentManager fm = (FragmentActivity)context.getSupportFragmentManager(); //getting error at this line.
//Called like the above
new ToolBarGenerator(getActivity())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Context` you have is from the `FragmentActivity`, you can just cast it to `FragmentActivity`, though I don't know for sure if that's your case.

That said, it sounds like what you're doing is bad practice. I would keep all Fragment transactions within the `FragmentActivity` class. If another class needs to request a different `Fragment` shown, you should use callbacks or something similar.

Comment: public ToolBarGenerator(Context c){context =c;}  //MyClass              FragmentManager fm = (FragmentActivity)context.getSupportFragmentManager(); <br>            I did like the above but I am getting error

Comment: Change the parameter from `Context` to `FragmentActivity` and pass that in as a parameter instead.

Comment: With context cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Answer (score 1):

Just answered this in another thread, but this may help others.  I was in a situation perhaps similar to yours with no precise answers for how to work around having an `Adapter` class separate from the `FragmentActivity` class, while needing to access the `getSupportFragmentManager`() within the Adapter.

Passing the context didn't work because it doesn't allowing casting of the FragmentActivity (for reasons I still don't understand).

But I gave up and just saved access to the manager itself and call it directly:

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
    super(fm);  
    _fm = fm; // declared in the class "private FragmentManager _fm;"
    _context=context;       
}
```